# MongoDb request can take from 2 seconds to 70 seconds

Tags: asp.net, mongodb

I have a Web app (ASP.NET) using a mongoDB database with 500,000 documents. Sometimes a query (measured through a log I created in ASP.NET) takes 2 seconds, sometimes I get a *HttpException : Request timed out*. Once it took 70s. When it times out (after several minutes), if I retry immediately after that, it takes 2s.

I use the C# mongoDB driver and the connection timeout is set to 15s. Does this mean the delay is not caused by the actual query (otherwise the timeout would kick in)?
What could be the issue?

It doesn't seem to be linked with a particular query.

Answer (score 0):

To verify the performance of queries in mongodb, one can use the performance measurement tools provided by mongodb.

One can simulate your query by passing the parameters diirectly to mongodb and execute the `explain` function to get some insights (time spent in the query being one of them).

For example, let's say one has something like:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "f1", type: "food", quantity: 500 }
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : "f2", type: "food", quantity: 100 }
{ "_id" : 3, "item" : "p1", type: "paper", quantity: 200 }
{ "_id" : 4, "item" : "p2", type: "paper", quantity: 150 }
{ "_id" : 5, "item" : "f3", type: "food", quantity: 300 }
{ "_id" : 6, "item" : "t1", type: "toys", quantity: 500 }
{ "_id" : 7, "item" : "a1", type: "apparel", quantity: 250 }
{ "_id" : 8, "item" : "a2", type: "apparel", quantity: 400 }
{ "_id" : 9, "item" : "t2", type: "toys", quantity: 50 }
{ "_id" : 10, "item" : "f4", type: "food", quantity: 75 }
```

and executes the following query:

```
db.inventory.find( { quantity: { $gte: 100, $lte: 200 } } )
```

To get the execution time, one could do something like:

```
db.inventory.find(
   { quantity: { $gte: 100, $lte: 200 } }
).explain("executionStats")
```

The referenced command would return something similar to this:

```
{
   "queryPlanner" : {
         "plannerVersion" : 1,
         ...
         "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
            ...
         }
   },
   "executionStats" : {
      "executionSuccess" : true,
      "nReturned" : 3,
      "executionTimeMillis" : 0,
      "totalKeysExamined" : 0,
      "totalDocsExamined" : 10,
      "executionStages" : {
         "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
         ...
      },
      ...
   },
   ...
}
```

As one can see from the result, **executionTimeMillis** is probably the parameter one is looking for. This example was taken from the manual. One can take a better look there:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/analyze-query-plan/

That being said, indexing one's collection can improve query performance, I suggest one taking a look at the following link:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/

Hope my answer was helpful.

Comment: Thanks but I am not looking to optimize the query at this point. I am trying to figure out why it is so inconsistent and even if it is the culprit.